# How to have a grub like in Ubuntu-Light?

Tags: grub2, themes, burg, ubuntu-light

How can I make my grub screen look like that of Ubuntu Light. I would like to have a GRUB menu similar to this picture:

[image: http://www.muylinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/UbuntuLight1.jpg]

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a [BURG](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/beautiful-burg-boot-loader-gets-ubuntu-11-04-ppa/) theme. I'm not sure where you could get the theme itself, but you could probably find something at [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org) for it.

Comment: Definitely BURG. The theme is probably called Ubuntu-Light and I wouldn't be surprised if it was one of the default themes actually.

Comment: @zookalicious Found out that [Ubuntu Light](http://www.canonical.com/engineering-services/oem-services/why-ubuntu/products) is actually an official version of Ubuntu released by Canonical for OEMs. In the PDF datasheet found in a link there, this theme is shown, so I'm guessing it was officially supported by Canonical. It'd be great to see this used in "mainstream" Ubuntu, possibly after 12.04.